# Get the number of matched characters in a regex group

Tags: php, regex

I may be pushing the boundaries of Regular Expressions, but who knows...

I'm working in php.

In something like:

```
preg_replace('/(?:\n|^)(={3,6})([^=]+)(\1)/','<h#>$2</h#>', $input);
```

Is there a way to figure out how many '=' `(={3,6})` matched, so I can backreference it where the '#'s are?

Effectively turning:

```
===Heading 3=== into <h3>Heading 3</h3>
====Heading 4==== into <h4>Heading 4</h4>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
preg_replace('/(?:\n|^)(={3,6})([^=]+)(\1)/e',
             "'<h'.strlen('$1').'>'.'$2'.'</h'.strlen('$1').'>'", $input);
```

[Ideone Link](http://ideone.com/iUEYA)

Answer (score 2):

No, PCRE can't do that. You should instead use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and do some character counting then:

```
  preg_replace_callback('/(?:\n|^)(={3,6})([^=]+)(\1)/', 'cb_headline', $input);

  function cb_headline($m) {
      list(, $markup, $text) = $m;

      $n = strlen($markup);
      return "<h$n>$text</h$n>";
  }
```

Additionally you might want to be forgiving with the trailing `===` signs. Don't use a backreference but allow a variable number.

You might also wish to use the `/m` flag for your regex, so you can keep `^` in place of the more complex `(?:\n|^)` assertion.

Comment: +1, and while you're at it, replace the `(?:\n|^)` with `(?m)^` (i.e., turn on multiline mode so `^` becomes a *start-of-line* anchor instead of *start-of-string).

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple with modifier `e` in regexp, no need in `preg_replace_callback`

```
$str = '===Heading 3===';
echo preg_replace('/(?:\n|^)(={3,6})([^=]+)(\1)/e',
     'implode("", array("<h", strlen("$1"), ">$2</h", strlen("$1"), ">"));', 
$str);
```

or this way

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:\n|^)(={3,6})([^=]+)(\1)/e',
     '"<h".strlen("$1").">$2</h".strlen("$1").">"', 
$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php
$input = '===Heading 3===';
$h_tag = preg_replace_callback('#(?:\n|^)(={3,6})([^=]+)(\1)#', 'paragraph_replace', $input);
var_dump($h_tag);

function paragraph_replace($matches) {
    $length = strlen($matches[1]);
    return "<h{$length}>". $matches[2] . "</h{$length}>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
string(18) "<h3>Heading 3</h3>"
```